# Include Additional HTTPS Request Header Information in Form

Tags: html, forms, authentication, http-headers

Is there a way to include additional request headers in form data, other than `action` and `method`?  I am hoping to send some authentication credentials cross domain without making the user re-enter their login credentials. ie I want to build an Authentication header directly from form submission.

The domain is SSL enabled, so I considered including credentials in the URL, but as explained [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/758002.html) this is a bad idea, as those credentials may be secure over the connection, but can be accessed through the browser by other apps potentially.

**Larger Picture**

I have access to the cross domain username and password through an AJAX request to the client server (home domain).  I want to take those credentials and submit them through a non-AJAX request, so a user can download a document securely without the URL being publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the specific question, I believe the answer is no - you can't control sending any extra headers from the form itself. There are some other things you can send with a form, but they are not useful to what you want to do: [W3 Form Tag Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

What you could do is do a form POST, which is the standard way to communicate when sessions cookies are out of the question and a query string won't do; just use a hidden field with some sort of token/hash of the credentials. Avoid clear-text of passwords like the plague, and really try to avoid reversible encryption of them too. This is just one of those areas you have to be extra careful to avoid creating an easily exploitable security vulnerability.

But generally speaking it works just fine, and anything that can do an AJAX GET should be able to do an AJAX POST.

Comment: So I was suspecting something along these lines.  When I submit a form and say i have `<input type="hidden" name="username" value="userhash"/>` and `<input type="hidden" name="password" value="pwdhash"/>` and I submit the form, the username and value will not be exposed in a query string?  I've used Django before and it seems that this is how it did authentication.  Am I understanding you?

Comment: You sure are! This is one of the differences in GET vs POST form action. In a GET request the form is url-encoded and passed along in the HTTP request URL, but in POST the url-encoded data is actually sent in the body of the HTTP request - the URL itself is not altered. The effect is that there is no way to bookmark a form POST, so you can't just click a link and be logged in automatically - unless you program your server-side logic that way.